# Matching ranges with regex in a string

Tags: r

I have a list of codes, which have a structure of a letter followed by two digits, and I would like to extract the codes that start with a certain letter and contain digits in a certain range. Let's say I have codes like these:

```
A01
A03
A06
A12
A99
B01
C09
```

and I would like to extract `A[01-12]` so I end up with 4 codes. How do I do that in R? I looked around for the answer to this question but I couldn't find anything relevant. Thanks for help.

Comment: If I had to do this, I'd split the code into two separate columns in my `data.frame`. It'd make filtering easier with tools form `dplyr`

Comment: Actually that's a really good idea. I haven't thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: First devise an algorithm by which you want to obtain your result. Try solving it with the tools you know and when you get stuck, edit your question where you get stuck.

Comment: Try to filter this column using `paste0("A", formatC(1:12, width=2, flag="0"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example of how you might split your identifier into two columns for filtering.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Code=c("A01",
                        "A03",
                        "A06",
                        "A12",
                        "A99",
                        "B01",
                        "C09"))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(Code1 = substr(Code,1,1)) %>%
  mutate(Code2= as.numeric(substr(Code,2,3)))

df %>%
  filter(Code1=="A" & Code2<=12)
```

It has the advantage of being flexible for filtering and you could remove the columns after filtering should you wish.

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful.

Comment: Edited for `Code2 <=12` thanks @AntoniosK for spotting

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be:

```
string <- c("A01", "A03", "A06", "A12", "A99", "B01", "C09")

string[grepl("(?<=A)[0-1](?<!1)[1-9]|(?<=A)[0-1](?<=1)[1-2]", string, perl = TRUE)]

[1] "A01" "A03" "A06" "A12"
```